# Parse Pandas dataframe columns to check for the same value

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am working out of a huge csv file (873,323 x 271) that looks similar to what is below:

```
| Part_Number |   Type_Code   |  Building_Code | Handling_Code | Price to Buy | Price to Sell |      Name     |
|:-----------:|:-------------:|:--------------:|:-------------:|:------------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|
|      A      |      1, 2     |   XX, XX, XX   | Y, Y, Y, Y, Y |    304.32    |      510      |     Mower     |
|      B      |    1, 1, 1    |   XX, XX, XX   |   Y, Y, Y, Y  |    1282.04   |      5000     |      Saw      |
|      C      |    1, 2, 3    |     XX, XX     |      Y, Y     |     68.91    |       65      | Barrel (Hard) |
|      D      | 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 | XX, XX, XX, XX |    Y, Y, Y    |       0      |      300      | Barrel (Make) |
|      E      |       1       |       XX       |   Y, Y, Y, Y  |    321.11    |      415      |  Cement Mixer |
|      F      |       2       |   XX, XX, XX   |       Y       |    194.44    |      1095     |   Cement Mix  |
```

There are a mix of column types: Some are numerical, some are string, and some are strings that look like lists (i.e., `Type_Code`, `Building_Code`, `Handling_Code`, etc.)

What I am trying to accomplish is:

> If each value in the column is the same value, then remove the list-like structure and replace it with just that value. i.e., 1, 1, 1 should become just 1. Numerical and non list-like strings should not be changed

Morphing the above table:

```
| Part_Number | Type_Code | Building_Code | Handling_Code | Price to Buy | Price to Sell |      Name     |
|:-----------:|:---------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|:------------:|:-------------:|:-------------:|
|      A      |    1, 2   |       XX      |       Y       |    304.32    |      510      |     Mower     |
|      B      |     1     |       XX      |       Y       |    1282.04   |      5000     |      Saw      |
|      C      |  1, 2, 3  |       XX      |       Y       |     68.91    |       65      | Barrel (Hard) |
|      D      |     1     |       XX      |       Y       |       0      |      300      | Barrel (Make) |
|      E      |     1     |       XX      |       Y       |    321.11    |      415      |  Cement Mixer |
|      F      |     2     |       XX      |       Y       |    194.44    |      1095     |   Cement Mix  |
```

(i.e., since `Building_Code` was just aggregations of `XX`, it should just say `XX`)

Below is my current my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in CSV
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\wundermahn\\Desktop\\test_stack_csv.csv')

# Turn all columns into a list
for col in df.columns:
    col_name = str(col)
    temp = pd.DataFrame(df[col_name].tolist())
    df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)
    df = pd.concat([df, temp], axis=1, join='inner')

# Now loop through the columns and remove items from the list
for col in df.columns:
    # If all items are the same
    if (len(set(col)) <= 1):
        # Set it to be that item
        col = col[0]
    else:
        # If they aren't the same, then just take the items out of the list
        col = str(col)

print(df)
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\wundermahn\Desktop\stack_0318.py", line 15, in <module>
    if (len(set(col)) <= 1):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: I know you should censor your data, but *Building_Code was just aggregations of XX, it should just say XX* doesn't make much sense. Are the `XX, XX,XX` in a cell the same value? Or how do you aggregate them?

Comment: Right, they are the exact same value. They are aggregated in the database, unfortunately I don't have any ability to change the aggregation protocol :( . You could imagine `XX, XX, XX ` as being equivalent to: `BC103, BC103, BC103 `. Sorry that it was confusing.

Comment: And the `Y`'s are also the same, but you want to break them? Do you see why it might be confusing?

Comment: Right... if it is all the same value in the cell, I want that removed to be a single value of the cell. `Y, Y, Y, Y, Y` should be `Y`, as `Y, Y` should be `Y`, as `Quang Hoang, Quang Hong, Quang Hong, Quang Hong, Quang Hong ` should be `Quang Hong`. I'm not disagreeing that the data was assembled poorly, but it is my job to fix that via a Python program, which is why I am posting here -- I found no other similar SO posts and think this is an interesting parsing problem.

Comment: do you know the column names beforehand? also what would be expected you you had an entry like `1,1,2,3` in a cell: leave that cell or `1,2,3` ?

Comment: Great question @anky_91, and something I did not post. That is my fault. I would expect `1, 1, 2, 3` to turn into `1, 2, 3`. As for knowing the column names beforehand, I do not unfortunately, though I think I can use `list(data.columns)` for that, as I have in the past.

Comment: Am I missing something from `f = lambda x:','.join(dict.fromkeys([i.strip() for i in x.split(',')]).keys())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a custom function which splits `,` and joins it back after removing duplicates for which I have used `dict.fromkeys`

```
f = lambda x:','.join(dict.fromkeys([i.strip() for i in x.split(',')]).keys())

df.loc[:,df.dtypes.eq('object')]=df.select_dtypes('O').applymap(f)
```

---

```
print(df)

   Part_Number Type_Code Building_Code Handling_Code  Price to Buy  \
0           A       1,2            XX             Y        304.32   
1           B         1            XX             Y       1282.04   
2           C     1,2,3            XX             Y         68.91   
3           D         1            XX             Y          0.00   
4           E         1            XX             Y        321.11   
5           F         2            XX             Y        194.44   

   Price to Sell           Name  
0            510          Mower  
1           5000            Saw  
2             65  Barrel (Hard)  
3            300  Barrel (Make)  
4            415   Cement Mixer  
5           1095     Cement Mix
```